# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

AfterCasting OLD Object Type `org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssessmentData@b7a641`

AfterCreating NEW OBJECT TYPE `org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssessmentData@16091af`

AfterCasting OLD Object CLASS  `org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssessmentData`

AfterCasting NEW Object CLASS `org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssessmentData`

These are the statements i printed in the below for loop...

```
for(int i=0;i<pendingAssessdataList.size();i++)
        {
            AssessmentData ad=(AssessmentData)pendingAssessdataList.get(i);
            AssessmentData new_a = afq.prepareAssessment(ad, ServerConfigurationService.getServerUrl());    

openSession.save(new_a);
            }
```

At the point of session save(newObject) this exception is raising aborting the saving of object in the session.
Even after the instances are same why it is not able to save the object in session?

Comment: Does the object `pendingAssessdataList` hold the object of `AssessmentData` ?

Comment: yes pendingAssessdataList contains AssessmentData objects only and also they are able ClassCast that u can see in the above code